# compare lists containing strings and return boolean list with the same order

Tags: python-3.x

I have main list with string values that all other lists should be compared against.

`main_lst = ['B-1', 'C-1', 'B-3', 'D-3', 'D-1', 'D-2', 'D-4', 'E-1']`

Sample list that should be compared with main list:

`smpl = ['B-1', 'D-3', 'D-1']`

Result should be list with values 1 if string exists and 0 otherwise (boolean):

`result = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]` with the same order as in main list

Following code is returning boolean but with different order.

`bool_list = [elem in flwline for elem in all_wells]`

`[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

How can the desired `result` be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = [1 if item in smpl else 0 for item in main_lst]
```

which gives:

```
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```